# How to find only the edges of an image to find corner points

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to detect the corner points of an image so that I can rotate in order to remove tilt of that image.

I followed the steps mentioned in the [[http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/]](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/%5d)

But I am able to rotate only the image that is mentioned in that example.

If I am trying to apply the same code for other images containing text(ex:`driving license`),the text inside the image is also getting detected as lines and I am not getting the exact corner points of the image.

I am new to android.So please help me out.

Comment: Hi @user3571635 can Please correct that link...

Comment: @Don'tBenegative  That's  completely a negligible edit.

Comment: Why You are Negative about Me @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ .....